# Can't return a string in Java

Tags: java, string

Below is my Java code. I'm trying to parse html files for links only. I send in the files, and printed the array under **parseURL** worked fine. But when I return it and set it as parray, suddenly parray is all null. Any ideas why?

```
public String[] getWebPages(Document doc) throws IOException
{

    Elements pages = doc.select("a[href]").not("a[href$=gz]").not("a[href$=jar").not("a[href$=rar").not(
            "a[href$=zip").not("a[href$=mdb").not("a[href$=doc").not("a[href$=docx").not("a[href$=odt").not(
                    "a[href$=pdf").not("a[href$=ppt").not("a[href$=pptx").not("a[href$=wks");

    for (Element page : pages) 
    {
        System.out.println("\nDownloading next page...");
        String url = page.absUrl("href");
        System.out.println(url);
        parray = parseURL(url,page);

           System.out.println(parray[0]);
           System.out.println(parray[2]);
           System.out.println(parray[3]);
           System.out.println(parray[4]);
           System.out.println(parray[5]);
           System.out.println(parray[6]);
           System.out.println(parray[7]);
           System.out.println(parray[8]);
           System.out.println(parray[9]);


    }

    return parray;


   }



 public String[] parseURL(String url, Element page)
    {

     Boolean boo = true;

        if (url.indexOf("#") != -1)
            {
                System.out.println("Non-page...discarding page.");
                return null;
            }

        for(x=0; x<500; x++)
        if(url.equals(array[x]))
        {
            return null;
        }

        array[i] = url;
           i++;

           System.out.println(array[1]);
           System.out.println(array[2]);
           System.out.println(array[3]);
           System.out.println(array[4]);
           System.out.println(array[5]);
           System.out.println(array[6]);
           System.out.println(array[7]);
           System.out.println(array[8]);
           System.out.println(array[9]);



        return array;
    }
```

Comment: After the loop, `parray` will be the result of the last call to `parseURL(url,page);`, if that's `null`, you'll end up with `null`.

Comment: `for(x=0; x<500; x++)` nice magic number.. why 500?

Comment: This kinda seems better suited to [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: 500 was an insane maximum I chose. Like I said below, most code is just checking for whether or not it is null. It'll all be deleted eventually.

Comment: What is the initial value of i in parseURL? If it's >0 then we might be in trouble.

Comment: You could at least use `array.length` instead of 500.

Comment: Great point. Now in use. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you're using a for loop, and inside the loop, you get new data, and discard all data obtained from the previous iteration of the loop, so most of the data is discarded and wasted.

Consider creating either a 2D array, or probably better, a List of List, `List<List<String>>`, so you can hold all the results returned in the for loop.

i.e.,

```
List<String> parseUrl(...) {

}
```

and then,

```
List<List<String>> parsedInfo = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
while (stillHavePages) {
  // parse pages and add to list above
}
```

Comment: Or just use `array` instead of `parray` and ignore `parseURL`s return value (which will be either `array` or `null`). This is very weird code.

Comment: But shouldn't it stay constant inside the for-loop? At least for one iteration? Parray should be valid for one whole set I would think. Maybe not. I'll rework it.

Comment: And yes, it is insanely weird code. A good bit is just checking for null stuff or not so that's why it's all jumbled.

Comment: @user3010468: I have no idea. All I know is that you're using magic numbers in a for loop that shouldn't have magic numbers. Just say no to them.

Comment: @user3010468 You are returning `null` from `parseURL()` if the URL is already in `array` or doesn't contain a "#". Your `parray` ends up being set to `null` in that case, regardless of what's in `array`. You're confusing yourself because you have hard coded numbers, strange mixes of locals vs. fields, and unnecessary reassignments all over the place.

Comment: @user3010468 yes, I believe you should at least get to print out some data in the 1st iteration. Is parray a class variable that is being edited somewhere else?

Comment: Nope it's just a holder variable.

Comment: Think I'll listen to Hovercraft. Thanks a ton guys!

Comment: A "holder variable"...?